# Why is AngularJS adding extra classes to server-generated output?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am generating (via Jade + Express.js + Node.js) an HTML page where I am setting the `value` of an `input[text]` element. However, even though this value is set properly (verified by viewing source code; Ctrl+U in FF), the interface shows a blank text box, and inspecting the element in FF shows extra AngularJS classes added to that `input[text]` element.

Appropriate line in the Jade template:

```
input(type="text", class="form-control", tabindex=1, id="episodeVal", ng-model="epName", value="#{epName}")
```

Output from Jade, generated via Node.js (which is exactly as per expectation):

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" id="episodeVal" ng-model="epName" value="Arbit" class="form-control">
```

"Computed" (correct word?) output shown by Firefox's "Inspect element" (this shows extra AngularJS classes added):

```
<input tabindex="1" id="episodeVal" ng-model="epName" value="Arbit" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text">
```

Why is AngularJS adding these additional classes? Am I correct in thinking that this is what is preventing the browser from showing the `value` set for `input[text]`?

Please let me know if any extra information is needed.

**Update 1:** Just noticed that the enclosing form also has extra `ng-pristine` and `ng-valid` applied to it) and the FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution that worked for me was using `ng-init` to initialize the value of `epName` (fragment of Jade template syntax):

```
ng-init="epName = \"#{epName}\";"
```

which outputs HTML (fragment):

```
ng-init="epName = &quot;New One&quot;;"
```

on the `input` tag.

Thanks to @Chandermani for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

No the extra classes are not affecting the behaviour.

This classes are there describing the state of the form. See the documentation on [Angular Forms](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/guide/forms) to know what is the significance of these classes.

Coming to your issue, even if you set the value property, since you are using `ng-model="epName"`, whatever is there in `$scope.epName` will be set on the `input`.

Comment: I am not setting the value of `$scope.epName` to anything. How do I get the `input[text]`'s `value` to show up? I can't set the value of `$scope.epName` on the server...

Comment: Since ng-model is used to support two way binding, you need to initialize the `epName` with the value that you want to show. It cannot be initialize with value property of input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set value in angular the input will automatically show she value your model in JS has. So if the epModel in JS equals to 'someValue', input value will be automatically set to that.

So instead of setting the value of the input, set it in javascript if you already haven't